# Why is sql MAX function not working properly?

Tags: php, sql, max

I have this query working to some extent. 
It returns the correct value for 'rating' (which output as 7, the highest rating), but the output for 'content' is from a different row in the table. (not the row of the highest rating, which is 7)

```
$bestAnswerQuery = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT content, MAX(rating) as rating FROM answers WHERE questionID = '$questionID'");

$fetchBestAnswer = MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC($bestAnswerQuery);

echo "$fetchBestAnswer[content] $fetchBestAnswer[rating]";
```

Can anyone tell me why? I've searched and cannot find out why this isn't working properly.

Comment: So, you're trying to get the highest rating and the content that has that rating for a given question?

Comment: I guess I didn't know exactly how to handle aggregated functions. I didn't know they had to have the GROUP BY clause. 
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not how aggregates like `MAX` work in SQL. Your confusion is coming from MySQL's (default) non-ANSI handling of aggregates.

Aggregates like `MAX` operate over groups. In the absence of a `group by` clause, the entire result set is considered to be a single group. Only expressions that are part of a `group by` clause can be included in a `select` clause without being enclosed in an aggregate. In the case where there is no `group by`, then all columns or expressions in the `select` clause must be contained in an aggregate.

However, MySQL's default configuration breaks this by allowing you to include non-grouped expressions in the `select` clause, but the row that any given expression uses to obtain its value is undefined; it could be any row within the group.

After that long-winded answer, if what you want to get is the maximum `rating` and the associated `content` column from the table for a given question, you can just do this:

```
select 
    rating, 
    content 

from answers 

where questionID = '$questionID' 

order by rating desc 

limit 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even think about ordering rating in descending order and limiting it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query a little like this:

```
$bestAnswerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT content, rating as rating 
          FROM answers 
          WHERE questionID = '$questionID'
            AND rating = MAX(rating)");
```

Comment: This would return multiple rows in the event that two answers for a given question had the same maximum rating.

Comment: @AdamRobinson and how will it affect the result, since OP is only `echo`ing a single row!

Comment: True enough, but I think it's important that the OP know how to structure the query properly so that there are no surprises if the method if presentation is changed.